# How can I replace a style in a presentation with another one?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a number of presentations where I show code examples. Each one is a lesson in a course.

I have not been very systematic: in some presentations I use the `menlo` style. In others I use `consolas`. I also sometimes mix both in the same presentation. Bad, bad me!

I now would like to make everything more consistent. Going through each and every slide in every presentation to change the style is my punishment.

But is there a way to make that change global ? I mean is there a way to replace a style globally in a presentation ? In multiple presentations ?

Comment: As long as the text formatting can identify it uniquely and conclusively as a code example rather than something else, this should be possible to do throughout a presentation or, with more work, in multiple presentations.  But this is a "help you fix your code" site, not a "write it for you" site, so you'll need to have a go at it first and ask here about problems that arise.

Comment: I only use those styles (menlo or consolas) for text boxes that contain code (I never use them for anything else). I am not asking for anyone to "write it for me". Mostly I want to know if there is some kind of "global search/replace" in Powerpoint that gets me there: I have found nothing of the like ... If you are hinting that I should use VBA or any other scripting that is fine as long as the learning curve is not longer than the time it takes me to do all the changes manually (probably a few hours).

Comment: There's nothing in Powerpoint's feature set that will help with this but as long as the text is in text boxes or text placeholders and isn't grouped with other shapes or part of smart-art or the like, a bit of VBA wouldn't be very difficult to write. Say, to look at the font of each shape with text and if it's menlo, convert it to consolas. Or vice versa. If there's likely to be consolas/menlo text in the same text box as other text, it gets a wee bit trickier. I can give you a bit of VBA to get you started if you like.

Comment: Thanks, A bit of VBA to get me started would be great. I have never touched that ... My text is always in isolated text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter:

```
Option Explicit

' Edit these to reflect the names of the fonts
' you want to change from and to:
Const ChangeFromFont As String = "Consolas"
Const ChangeToFont As String = "Courier New"

Sub ChangeFontName()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
        If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                If UCase(.Font.Name) = UCase(ChangeFromFont) Then
                    .Font.Name = ChangeToFont
                End If
            End With
        End If
        End If
    Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great. I did one more thing in the code: I used it to also remove the shading from the text boxes, and added some counting. Thanks again. I am going to keep this code around !

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind As I said, it was just a starter. I kind of figured you'd run with it.  Great!